# php ajax two select box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I am quite new to this jquery ajax. What I want to know is how can I populate the content of my second select box based on the selection from the first select box. Say here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="tosomewhere.php">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="first" name="year">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="second" name="section">
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

The jscript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#first").change(function () {
$("#second").load('second_option.php?year=', {first: $(this).val()});
});
});
</script>
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php

require '../../config/dbconfig.php';
$year = $_GET['year'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM section_tb WHERE year = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($year));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$second_option = "";
foreach($result as $key => $value)
    $second_option .= "<option value='".$value['section_name']."'>".$value['section_name']."</option>";
echo $second_option;
?>
```

The content of my second select box will be populated from a mysql results of WHERE value of first select box. I can build the PHP file, I'm just confuse on how to return and populate it on the select.

Any leads to tutorials or samples? Thank you so much.

EDIT: Added the jquery script, but still no luck. I tried to var_dump($second_option) it has contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this javascript to your current page:

```
<script>
$(function () {

  $("#first").change(function () {
    $("#second").load('second_options.php?year=' + $(this).val());
  });

});
</script>
```

And return this content in your "second_options.php":

```
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried this, with some adjustments, `$("#second").load('second_options.php?year=', {first: $(this).val()});`, then on my PHP, I get the year value. I foreach the result of my query to <option>. But nothing appears.

Comment: If you access your 'second_options.php?year=1' page directly in the browser, do you see the options returned in the source?  If you get any kind of error, the .load() function will die silently, which may be what you're seeing here.

Comment: It doesn't return the `echo $second_option;`. But when I add this `<html><body><select><?php echo $second_option; ?></select></body></html>`, it does display an option containing what I fetch from the database.

Comment: I tried to replace the content of `$second_option = "HELLO";` it does return the "HELLO" when I change the first drop down. Why is it if the content of the `$second_option = "<option></option>";` is like this, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I think the way you are passing the year parameter back is not right - I've changed my example to be more similar to how you're doing it, but in such a way that should actually work.  As far as the content of the response - it should only be <option>foo</option><option>bar</option> (etc...) with no wrapping HTML at all.

Comment: Also - make sure that when the jQuery code makes the request, there is no error being thrown.  Check this with either Chrome or FireBug, within the network traffic analysis tools in either of those.

Answer (score 0):

here are some tutorials

www.huanix.com/files/dependent_select/dependent_select.php

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/708593-dependent-dropdown-list-mysql

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php